# How do you vertically center items in Jumbotron using flex while displaying in block?

Tags: css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I tried this to vertically center all items in a Jumbotron,

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

But the issue is all items are lined up in a single line like they are displaying inline.  How do you vertically center them while still displaying them in block.

Comment: Could you provide your code to the jumbotron. I don't really understand why your content wouldn't be **vertically** centered when jumbotron has the same amount of padding applied both to the top and the bottom.

Comment: @Klooven please read my question again and you will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `block` element stacks vertically, change the flex direction to *column*, and so will the flex items.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;              /*  added  */
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above answer, you can also center text elements such as `h1`, `p` or `a` by setting text-align to center.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;              
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;                    /*  aligning items  */
text-align: center;                     /*  aligning text  */
```